# jquery.tinyscrollbar pop-up scroll bar not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

- Original demo http://jsfiddle.net/anglimass/NVTzx/9/
- Updated demo (that actually demonstrates the problem) http://jsfiddle.net/NVTzx/16/

Please click "see all" then show one pop up. The pop-up appears but the scrollbar is not working.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();    
});

//SETTING UP OUR POPUP
//0 means disabled; 1 means enabled;
var popupStatus = 0;

//loading popup with jQuery magic!
function loadPopup(){
    //loads popup only if it is disabled
    if(popupStatus==0){
        jQuery("#backgroundPopup").css({
            "opacity": "0.7"
        });
        jQuery("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
        jQuery("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");
        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}

//disabling popup with jQuery magic!
function disablePopup(){
    //disables popup only if it is enabled
    if(popupStatus==1){
        jQuery("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
        jQuery("#popupContact").fadeOut("slow");
        popupStatus = 0;
    }
}

//centering popup
function centerPopup(){
    //request data for centering
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = jQuery("#popupContact").height();
    var popupWidth = jQuery("#popupContact").width();
    //centering
    jQuery("#popupContact").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2,
        "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2
    });
    //only need force for IE6

    jQuery("#backgroundPopup").css({
        "height": windowHeight
    });

}


//CONTROLLING EVENTS IN jQuery
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    //LOADING POPUP
    //Click the button event!
    jQuery("#button").click(function(){
        //centering with css
        centerPopup();
        //load popup
        loadPopup();
    });

    //CLOSING POPUP
    //Click the x event!
    jQuery("#popupContactClose").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
    });
    //Click out event!
    jQuery("#backgroundPopup").click(function(){
        none();
    });
    //Press Escape event!
    jQuery(document).keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
            disablePopup();
        }
    });

});

function LoadPop(){
        centerPopup();
        loadPopup();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="achieve">
    <h2><a href="#" id="button">(see all)</a></h2>
    <div class="achieve-container">

    </div>
</div>
<div id="popupContact">
    <div class="" id="contactArea">
            <div class="logbox">
                <div id="scrollbar1">
                <div class="scrollbar"><div class="track"><div class="thumb"><div class="end"></div></div></div></div>
                <div class="viewport">
                <div class="more-achive">
                    <h2>My Profile <a id="popupContactClose"><img src="images/close.gif" /></a></h2>
                    <div class="spacer"></div>
                    <div class="profstat">
                        <img src="images/pro-image1.gif" alt="Profile Image" />
                        <h1>Emily Hsiung</h1>
                        <p><span>567</span> Points</p>
                        <p><span>22</span> achievements</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="proflevelindicator">
                        <img src="images/level-indicator.gif" alt="level indicator" />
                        <h1>Level 5 Elephant Hunter</h1>
                        <p><span>33</span> Points to next level</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="spacer"></div>
                    <div class="achievelist">
                        <h2>Achievements</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div class="imagbox"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQB1T4_bghGtisR6Tom0Umf3FZHCQoPGFJgD0Orck3cB0F8iTZN" /></div>
                                <div class="titlebox">Spotlight</div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="imagbox"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQB1T4_bghGtisR6Tom0Umf3FZHCQoPGFJgD0Orck3cB0F8iTZN" /></div>
                                <div class="titlebox">15 Minutes of Fame</div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="imagbox"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQB1T4_bghGtisR6Tom0Umf3FZHCQoPGFJgD0Orck3cB0F8iTZN" /></div>
                                <div class="titlebox">Contributor</div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nomar">
                                <div class="imagbox"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQB1T4_bghGtisR6Tom0Umf3FZHCQoPGFJgD0Orck3cB0F8iTZN" /></div>
                                <div class="titlebox">Super Contributor</div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nomar1">
                                <div class="imagbox"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQB1T4_bghGtisR6Tom0Umf3FZHCQoPGFJgD0Orck3cB0F8iTZN" /></div>
                                <div class="titlebox">Share Your Toughts</div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nomar1">
                                <div class="imagbox"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQB1T4_bghGtisR6Tom0Umf3FZHCQoPGFJgD0Orck3cB0F8iTZN" /></div>
                                <div class="titlebox">shout From The Rooftops</div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nomar1">
                                <div class="imagbox"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQB1T4_bghGtisR6Tom0Umf3FZHCQoPGFJgD0Orck3cB0F8iTZN" /></div>
                                <div class="titlebox">15 Minutes of Fame</div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nomar">
                                <div class="imagbox"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQB1T4_bghGtisR6Tom0Umf3FZHCQoPGFJgD0Orck3cB0F8iTZN" /></div>
                                <div class="titlebox">Super Contributor</div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nomar1">
                                <div class="imagbox"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQB1T4_bghGtisR6Tom0Umf3FZHCQoPGFJgD0Orck3cB0F8iTZN" /></div>
                                <div class="titlebox">Share Your Toughts</div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nomar1">
                                <div class="imagbox"><img src="images/ach6.gif" /></div>
                                <div class="titlebox">shout From The Rooftops</div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nomar1">
                                <div class="imagbox"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQB1T4_bghGtisR6Tom0Umf3FZHCQoPGFJgD0Orck3cB0F8iTZN" /></div>
                                <div class="titlebox">15 Minutes of Fame</div>
                            </li>
                            <li style="margin:0 0 0 0;">
                                <div class="imagbox"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQB1T4_bghGtisR6Tom0Umf3FZHCQoPGFJgD0Orck3cB0F8iTZN" /></div>
                                <div class="titlebox">Contributor</div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="spacer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
```

Comment: I am getting JS error because i am missing JS files, do you get an error when using firebug?

Comment: yes i got js error. How do you get the missed file/

Comment: @t.k - my teammate solve that problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The JavaScript error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined` at `jquery.tinyscrollbar.js:54`. Looking at [the source](http://www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/js/jquery.tinyscrollbar.js), it is trying to find the scrollHeight with

```
oContent[options.axis] = oContent.obj[0]['scroll'+ sSize];
```

but oContent is defined as

```
var oContent = { obj: $('.overview', root) };
```

There is no element in your markup with `class="overview"`, so the script is failing.

I suggest following the examples from the site you seemed to have [downloaded the script from](http://www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/), in particular **HTML for a basic scrollbar**. The script is expecting markup that you have not got in your demo.

Answer (score 0):

I see a custom scroll bar, but no functions for scrolling. Are you ok with using the default browser scrollbars?

If you remove your scrollbar divs and replace `overflow:hidden` with `overflow:scroll` on your  `#scrollbar1 .viewport` property, the box will scroll with the default scroll bars.

**Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NVTzx/10/) demo.**

You could always go back and style the scrollbars with css, see [this article](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) from css tricks.

Hope that helps!